# WPF, cannot bind a property because it says it's not a DependencyProperty, but I registered it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a `UserControl` with a `Template` property that I've set up as a `DependencyProperty`:

```
public partial class TemplateDetail : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty _templateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Template",
            typeof(Template),
            typeof(TemplateDetail)
        );

    public TemplateDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Template = new Template();
        DataContext = Template;
    }

    public Template Template
    {
        get
        {
            return (Template)GetValue(_templateProperty);
        }
        set { SetValue(_templateProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use this `UserControl` in the XAML for a `Window`, SaveTemplateDialog, and I'm trying to set its `Template` property to the `Template` property in my `SaveTemplateDialog` class:

```
<local:TemplateDetail HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      MinWidth="100" Template="{Binding}"
                      Width="{Binding ElementName=Scroller, Path=ViewportWidth}"/>
```

The `DataContext` in `SaveTemplateDialog` is set to its `Template` property, which is also a dependency property.  However, for the XAML above, `Template="{Binding}"` is underlined in blue in Visual Studio and it says:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Template' property of type 'TemplateDetail'.  A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Sure enough, when I load my app, the contents of the `Template` that `TemplateDetail` tries to display is blank, when I know there are values in it.  Why does it give this message if I've registered `TemplateDetail.Template` as a dependency property?

**Edit:** now I'm quite confused.  In my `SaveTemplateDialog` window, I'm doing the following to pass along the template to the `TemplateDetail` `UserControl`:

```
<local:TemplateDetail HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      TemplateData="{Binding Path=NewTemplate, Mode=OneWay}"
                      Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

I know `Path=NewTemplate` is getting the right data because I also have this XAML in `SaveTemplateDialog`, which shows the value I would expect in the `MyType` property of `NewTemplate`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NewTemplate.MyType}" />
```

That `TextBlock` shows what I expect.  However, apparently the right data is not getting to `TemplateDetail` or I'm not binding correctly there, because I can't get that same `MyType` property (or the other `Template` properties) to show up in `TemplateDetail`.  In `TemplateDetail`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TemplateData.MyType}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="200"/>
```

And here's the `TemplateDetail` class as it is now:

```
public partial class TemplateDetail : MainWindowUserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "TemplateData",
            typeof(Template),
            typeof(TemplateDetail),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                new Template("Default Template", null)
            )
        );

    public TemplateDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public Template TemplateData
    {
        get
        {
            return (Template)GetValue(TemplateDataProperty);
        }
        set { SetValue(TemplateDataProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head if Template is a reserved word here.  Did you try a differently named dependency property?

Comment: @Robaticus:  I renamed the `TemplateDetail.Template` property to `TemplateData`; that got rid of the blue line and warning on the binding.  I'm still not seeing the template's data when I run my app, but that's probably a different problem.  Thanks!  You should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the name of your DependencyProperty to the use the standard convention like PropertyNameProperty instead of naming like a field. When you set something in XAML it calls SetValue and expects the property to be named using the string name ("Template" here) followed by "Property".

**UPDATE** for second question:

When you set `DataContext = this` in your TemplateDetail constructor that is causing the source for your Path=NewTemplate Binding to be changed from the inherited DataContext to the TemplateDetail control itself. You should be seeing an error in your Output window that the NewTemplate property can't be found on the object of type TemplateDetail. Instead of resetting the DataContext of the UserControl itself, I will usually give the root layout Panel in my UserControl XAML an x:Name and set `LayoutRoot.DataContext = this` in the constructor instead.

Comment: Hm.  I did this, referencing MSDN's page on dependency properties, but my app didn't show the data in the property after I had set the property in XAML.  My app always showed the initial, constructor-set value of the dependency property.  I tried switching from dependency properties to having my class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` but now it's back to saying "A 'Binding' cannot be set...".

Comment: That's a separate problem. You shouldn't be setting default values for DPs in the constructor of your control. Instead pass a PropertyMetadata into Register with your default value (for value types) or apply it through a default Style.

Comment: @John:  I changed it so that the default/initial value of my dependency property is set in the `Register` call.  I updated my question with my current problem.  Thanks!

Comment: @John:  thanks for the update.  I didn't realize the `DataContext` in the thing containing the `UserControl`  would change when I changed the `UserControl`'s `DataContext`.  I did what you suggested, though I'm 1) not seeing expected values still and 2) not seeing any errors in Output.

Comment: @John:  I *did* find some `System.Windows.Data Error`s in the Debug output, so I'm scouring those.

Comment: @John:  one last time--got it!  I had set an `x:Name` on the `<UserControl` in XAML, not on the main content container (`<Grid>` in my case).  Seeing errors in Debug output helps a great deal, too.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that Template isn't a reserved word that is causing the XAML processor to get confused.  Try a different word.

(posted as an answer per Sarah Vessel's suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

I think something is not getting updated as it should.  I found that if I did the following in my `NewTemplate` property in my `SaveTemplateDialog` window, then my `TemplateDetail` `UserControl` is properly filled out with all the data I expect:

```
public Template NewTemplate
{
    get
    {
        return (Template)GetValue(NewTemplateProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(NewTemplateProperty, value);

        // The magic line, explicitly setting TemplateData property on
        // the TemplateDetails UserControl:
        uct_templateDetails.TemplateData = value;
    }
}
```

This leads me to believe just having the following in `SaveTemplateDialog`'s XAML is not enough to send the new instance to `TemplateDetails` whenever `NewTemplate` is updated:

```
<local:TemplateDetail HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      TemplateData="{Binding Path=NewTemplate}" Grid.Row="2"
                      Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                      x:Name="uct_templateDetails"/>
```

I would love for someone to point out what I'm doing wrong here because it doesn't seem like I should have to explicitly say `uct_templateDetails.TemplateData = value;` whenever `SaveTemplateDialog.NewTemplate` is changed.  I thought that was the point of a dependency property, that updating it would cause things that use it to get the updated value.

Comment: You should never put any code other than the boilerplate SetValue call in your DP wrapper property: use a property changed callback instead. Any calls from XAML skip the wrapper and call SetValue directly, not to mention that anyone can call GetValue/SetValue from code.