# XAML bind to a property with @

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, windows-phone

i Have a class which has a @base  property.
The @ is required because "base" is a reserved word of the C# language.

How do i bind from XAML to this property?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513168/wpf-cannot-bind-a-property-because-it-says-its-not-a-dependencyproperty-but-i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`base` is a keyword in C# but not in XAML, therefore you can simply write...

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding base}" />
```

if you have something like this in the current DataContext:

```csharp
public string @base { get { return "Hello, World!"; } }
```

Keep in mind that `@` is not part of the property name in C#, it just means *the following token is an identifier*. The real property name is `base` even though you have to refer to it as `@base` in C#.

Comment: To Lucas' useful answer, I would add: if you can at all avoid it, do _not_ put yourself into a situation where you need to use the `@` to resolve a member name. I.e. just don't use reserved words for member names!

Comment: Completely agree with Peter. Add context to your variable names and then you avoid this situation.